# if $p(t)=\frac {t(t-1)...(t-2023)}{2023!}$ value of $\int_0^1 [\frac{1}{t+1} + \frac{1}{t+2} + ... + \frac{1}{t+2024}]p(-t-1) \,dt, = k^2$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

if $$p(t)=\frac {t(t-1)...(t-2023)}{2023!}$$ then the value of $$\int_0^1 \left[\frac{1}{t+1} + \frac{1}{t+2} + ... + \frac{1}{t+2024}\right]p(-t-1) \,dt = k^2$$

find k.

**my approach**

putting $-t-1$ in $p(t)$ gives $(t+1)(t+2)...(t+2024)$ which when put in the integral looked to me like a product of GM and HM of the series $t+1, t+2, ... $ but I couldn't really proceed from there

Comment: Could you verify if $k^2=2023$, i did the following $\frac{1}{2023!}\int_0^1\left(\sum_{r=0}^{2023}\frac{1}{t+r+1}\right)\left(\prod_{r=0}^{2023}t+r+1\right)\,dt=2023$

Comment: $k^2=2024^2$
$k=\pm 2024$

Comment: @ayan how did you solve that integral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $$f(t)=\prod_{i=1}^n (t+i), \quad t\in[0,1]$$
We can see using the chain rule that
$$f'(t) = \sum_{k=1}^n \prod_{i\neq k} (t+i)$$

Now notice that by expanding and canceling
$$\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{t+1}+\dots+\frac{1}{t+n}\right)(t+1)\cdots (t+n)\,dt = \int_0^1f'(t)\,dt=f(1)-f(0)=(n+1)!-n!=n\cdot n!$$

I believe you can take it from here.